# Use of 'Until' and 'Not' in a Sentence

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

Is the use of "not" in this sentence correct or not?

Don't communicate until the phone line is not fully secured.

Kindly advise.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Hot Licks ... thank you. Making sense is another thing. I am just trying to see if its use here is correct or incorrect.

Comment: It's incorrect because it's incoherent. Syntax does not require coherence, as Chomsky has demonstrated; but correctness, whatever you may think it means, does.

Comment: If one wanted to disseminate misinformation, and the line was fully secured, these instruction would make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you have a double negation in your sentence, so you're basically saying "wait for the phone line to be unsecure/unsafe, and then start communicating". From a grammatical standpoint, that sentence is 100% correct; there's nothing wrong with it. But, that's probably not what you meant to say (who would want to communicate over a dangerous, unsecure phone connection?). What you probably meant was, "wait for the phone line to be secure, and then start communicating". In that case, you would write:

> Don't communicate until the phone line is fully secured.

**EDIT**: changed "insecure" to "unsecure"

Comment: Unsecure and insecure mean different things. :)

Comment: @Davo you are correct. It should be "unsecure" instead of "insecure".

Comment: Thanks a million for the kind input.